# How to use the boost io_service with a priority queue?

Tags: boost

I have a program that have two function. one is a cycle timer, the other one is receiving some sockets.

I found that, if there were more then one packages coming in before the timer tirggered, the boost will run all the socket-handles and then run the timer-handle.

I wrote a simple code to simulate this timing like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

std::string get_time()
{
    struct timespec time_spec;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_spec);
    int h  = (int)(time_spec.tv_sec / 60 / 60 % 24);
    int m  = (int)(time_spec.tv_sec / 60 % 60);
    int s  = (int)(time_spec.tv_sec % 60);
    int ms = (int)(time_spec.tv_nsec / 1000);
    char st[50];
    snprintf(st, 50, "[%02d:%02d:%02d:%06d]", h, m, s, ms);

    return std::string(st);
}

void fA()
{
  std::cout << get_time() << " : fA()" << std::endl;
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(40));
}

void fB()
{
  std::cout << get_time() << " : fB()" << std::endl;
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(20));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io);

    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::steady_timer> t100ms = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(io);
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::steady_timer> t80ms = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(io);

    std::cout << get_time() << " : start" << std::endl;

    t100ms->expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    t80ms->expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(80));

    t100ms->async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &_error) {
        if(_error.value() == boost::system::errc::errc_t::success) {
            std::cout << get_time() << " : t100ms" << std::endl;
        }
    });
    t80ms->async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &_error) {
        if(_error.value() == boost::system::errc::errc_t::success) {
            std::cout << get_time() << " : t80ms" << std::endl;
            io.post(fA);
            io.post(fB);
        }
    });

    io.run();

    return 0;
}
```

The reuslt of this code is :

```
[08:15:40:482721] : start
[08:15:40:562867] : t80ms
[08:15:40:562925] : fA()
[08:15:40:603037] : fB()
[08:15:40:623186] : t100ms
```

But, the result I want is :

```
[08:15:40:482721] : start
[08:15:40:562867] : t80ms
[08:15:40:562925] : fA()
[08:15:40:603037] : t100ms
[08:15:40:604037] : fB()
```

The t100ms could be run between the fA and the fB, which time is more near the correct wantted time [`08:15:40:582721`] at the 100ms later from the start.

I found a [Invocation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp) example, which give an example for a priority queue.

And try to modify it by add my codes into this example.

```
    ...

    timer.async_wait(pri_queue.wrap(42, middle_priority_handler));


    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::steady_timer> t100ms = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(io_service);
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::steady_timer> t80ms = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(io_service);

    std::cout << get_time() << " : start" << std::endl;

    t100ms->expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    t80ms->expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(80));

    t100ms->async_wait(pri_queue.wrap(100, [&](const boost::system::error_code &_error) {
        if(_error.value() == boost::system::errc::errc_t::success) {
            std::cout << get_time() << " : t100ms" << std::endl;
        }
    }));
    t80ms->async_wait(pri_queue.wrap(100, [&](const boost::system::error_code &_error) {
        if(_error.value() == boost::system::errc::errc_t::success) {
            std::cout << get_time() << " : t80ms" << std::endl;
            io_service.post(pri_queue.wrap(0, fA));
            io_service.post(pri_queue.wrap(0, fB));
        }
    }));

    while (io_service.run_one())

    ...
```

But, the result still not shown as my mind. It like below:

```
[08:30:13:868299] : start
High priority handler
Middle priority handler
Low priority handler
[08:30:13:948437] : t80ms
[08:30:13:948496] : fA()
[08:30:13:988606] : fB()
[08:30:14:008774] : t100ms
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Handlers are run in the order in which they are posted.

When the 80ms expire, you immediately post both `fA()` and `fB()`. Of course, they will run first because t100ms is still pending.

Here's your example but much simplified:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2497b1e6fa650e76)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
using boost::asio::io_context;
using boost::asio::steady_timer;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace {
    static auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now;
    static auto get_time = [start = now()]{
        return "at " + std::to_string((now() - start)/1ms) + "ms:\t";
    };

    void message(std::string msg) {
        std::cout << (get_time() + msg + "\n") << std::flush; // minimize mixing output from threads
    }

    auto make_task = [](auto name, auto duration) {
        return [=] {
            message(name);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
        };
    };
}

int main() {
    io_context io;

    message("start");

    steady_timer t100ms(io, 100ms);
    t100ms.async_wait([&](auto ec) {
        message("t100ms " + ec.message());
    });

    steady_timer t80ms(io, 80ms);
    t80ms.async_wait([&](auto ec) {
        message("t80ms " + ec.message());
        post(io, make_task("task A", 40ms));
        post(io, make_task("task B", 20ms));
    });

    io.run();
}
```

Prints

```
at 0ms: start
at 80ms:        t80ms Success
at 80ms:        task A
at 120ms:       task B
at 140ms:       t100ms Success
```

### One Approach

Assuming you're really trying to time the operation, [consider running multiple threads](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b667285e82a28fba). With this three-word change the output is:

```
at 1ms: start
at 81ms:    t80ms Success
at 81ms:    task A
at 82ms:    task B
at 101ms:   t100ms Success
```

To serialize A and B still, post them on a strand by changing:

```
post(io, make_task("task A", 40ms));
post(io, make_task("task B", 20ms));
```

To

```
auto s = make_strand(io);
post(s, make_task("task A", 40ms));
post(s, make_task("task B", 20ms));
```

Now [prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdbabed43ac70b69)

```
at 0ms: start
at 80ms:        t80ms Success
at 80ms:        task A
at 100ms:       t100ms Success
at 120ms:       task B
```

(full listing below).

### No Thread Please

The other approach when you do no wish to use threads (for simplicity/safety e.g.), you will indeed require a queue. I'd consider writing it out as simply:

```
struct Queue {
    template <typename Ctx>
    Queue(Ctx context) : strand(make_strand(context)) {}

    void add(Task f) {
        post(strand, [this, f=std::move(f)] {
            if (tasks.empty())
                run();
            tasks.push_back(std::move(f));
        });
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::any_io_executor strand;
    std::deque<Task> tasks;

    void run() {
        post(strand, [this] { drain_loop(); });
    }

    void drain_loop() {
        if (tasks.empty()) {
            message("queue empty");
        } else {
            tasks.front()(); // invoke task
            tasks.pop_front();
            run();
        }
    }
};
```

Now we can safely choose whether we want it in a threaded context or not - because all queue operations are on a strand.

```
int main() {
    thread_pool io; // or io_context io;
    Queue tasks(io.get_executor());

    message("start");

    steady_timer t100ms(io, 100ms);
    t100ms.async_wait([&](auto ec) {
        message("t100ms " + ec.message());
    });

    steady_timer t80ms(io, 80ms);
    t80ms.async_wait([&](auto ec) {
        message("t80ms " + ec.message());
        tasks.add(make_task("task A", 40ms));
        tasks.add(make_task("task B", 40ms));
    });

    io.join(); // or io.run()
}
```

Using `thread_pool io;`:

```
at 0ms: start
at 80ms:        t80ms Success
at 80ms:        task A
at 100ms:       t100ms Success
at 120ms:       task B
at 160ms:       queue empty
```

Using `io_context io;` (or `thread_pool io(1);` of course):

```
at 0ms: start
at 80ms:        t80ms Success
at 80ms:        task A
at 120ms:       task B
at 160ms:       t100ms Success
at 160ms:       queue empty
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So dose it mean if I want the func100ms run at 100ms, I must use multi-threads? I tested the last codes with boost1.74 with Queue and thread_pool, and add an output of thread-id in the message() function, found that the t100ms and t80ms running in different threads.  (Sorry my English is poor) As I understood, with those codes I could run the t100ms and t80ms in a single same thread with `thread_pool io;`? I 've replaced the `Task` into `boost::function<void()>`, and not sure if it correct.